# Bootstrap multi level menu issues on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, dropdown

My problem is, that when i am looking at the site on mobile, i cant see the submenus.

For example:
I click down the "Alaplap" menu, then it displays the submenu, "Intel alaplap" and "amd alaplap". But the "Intel alaplap" also has a submenu, and i cant see that on mobile.

```
<ul class="nav nav-justified">
    <li><a href="https://projektar.hu/kategoria/4/alaplap" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Alaplap<b class="caret"></b></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="https://projektar.hu/kategoria/74/alaplap/intel-alaplap" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Intel alaplap</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="https://projektar.hu/kategoria/83/alaplap/intel-alaplap/asus-alaplap" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Asus alaplap</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="https://projektar.hu/kategoria/86/alaplap/intel-alaplap/asus-alaplap/asus-z370-alaplap">Asus Z370 alaplap</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="https://projektar.hu/kategoria/87/alaplap/intel-alaplap/asus-alaplap/asus-z390-express-alaplap" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Asus Z390 Express alaplap</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="https://projektar.hu/kategoria/88/alaplap/intel-alaplap/asus-alaplap/asus-z390-express-alaplap/aaa">aaaaa</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://projektar.hu/kategoria/89/alaplap/intel-alaplap/asus-alaplap/asus-z390-express-alaplap/bbb">bbbb</a></li>
</ul>
</li>    
</ul>
</li>
    <li><a href="https://projektar.hu/kategoria/84/alaplap/intel-alaplap/msi-alaplap">MSI alaplap</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://projektar.hu/kategoria/85/alaplap/intel-alaplap/gigabyte-alaplap">Gigabyte alaplap</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
    <li><a href="https://projektar.hu/kategoria/75/alaplap/amd-alaplap">AMD alaplap</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
    <li><a href="https://projektar.hu/kategoria/73/ssd-meghajto">SSD meghajtó</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://projektar.hu/kategoria/76/videokartya">Videókártya</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://projektar.hu/kategoria/77/memoria">Memória</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://projektar.hu/kategoria/78/tapegyseg">Tápegység</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://projektar.hu/kategoria/79/merevlemez">Merevlemez</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://projektar.hu/kategoria/80/monitor">Monitor</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://projektar.hu/kategoria/81/telefontok" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Telefontok<b class="caret"></b></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="https://projektar.hu/kategoria/82/telefontok/samsung-telefontok">Samsung telefontok</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

You can take a look at my demo site at here: [My demo site](https://projektar.hu/cookie-informaciok)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your site is still showing them in horizontal orientation when switching to responsive view which is always going to lead to a bad UX on mobile.  [This is how I would approach it myself](https://php.quicoto.com/bootstrap-3-second-level-menu-nav/). Feel fre to thank Ricard Torres if this was helpful.

```
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -6px;
  margin-left: -1px;
}
.dropdown-submenu:hover > .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-submenu:hover > a:after {
  border-left-color: #fff;
}
.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
  float: none;
}
.dropdown-submenu.pull-left > .dropdown-menu {
  left: -100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

and here is the actual html to power your menu...feel free to change the css accordingly.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>           
            <li class="dropdown">
               <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">                          
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second Level Menu ! <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Link 1</a></li>                           
                      <li><a href="#">Lik 2</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>                       
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li> <!-- .dropdown -->                        
          </ul> <!-- .nav .navbar-nav -->        
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

[Codepen solution to see it working](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjQqPO)